# Mysql Incorrect datetime value when doing select on timestamp with unixtime value

Tags: mysql

Okay, so I got this probably very easy problem, but only find answers for the opposite approach.

I have this mysql column:   `timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`

when i try to:

`select * from table where timestamp > 1440586108`

i get the following warning: `Incorrect datetime value '1440586108' for column timestamp at row 1`

How should i do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timestamp has format `yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s`

See [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

What you need is [FROM_UNIXTIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
Select * from table where timestamp > FROM_UNIXTIME(1440586108)
```

Comment: okay, but i got the time as unix timestamp, whats the correct mysql function to convert it to mysql timestamp format?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime looks like it will do what you want

Comment: when you accept my edit (adding from unixtime), i'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` like this

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE timestamp > FROM_UNIXTIME(1440586108)
```